# How do I save an XML file in ADLS using the Synapse Copy Activity?

Tags: xml, azure-synapse

I'm calling an api with xml as response and I need to write this to Azure Data Lake? But I do not see a sink dataset for XML in Synapse Copy Activity. Source dataset is http (binary). Sink is ADLS Gen 2 but I cannot see XML on the data format.

Thanks.

Comment: It's possible to use the Web activity to call a REST API which returns XML, however if the API has many pages, calling it in a For Each activity will be extremely expensive and a bad pattern.  Look for alternatives like a notebook or third-party tool compatible with SSIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently [XML format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/format-xml) is not supported in sink. You can raise a feature request from the synapse studio.

[image]

> Also, when using a [binary dataset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/format-binary) as a source in copy activity, you can only copy to a binary dataset in the sink.

**Source**:

[image]

**Sink**: Connect your sink dataset to binary format and copy the file.

[image]